# What is the simplest way to get the object a function is a method of with prototypes, now and later?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

In JavaScript, if I have:

```
var foo = function(){}

foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    console.log(this);
}

baz = new foo();
baz.name = 'baz';

bing = new foo();
bing.name = 'bing';

baz.bar();
bing.bar();

setTimeout(baz.bar);
setTimeout(bing.bar);
```

In my console I see the `baz`, `bing`, `window`, `window` objects logged, in that order.

What would be the simplest, or "normal" trickery required to see:

`baz`, `bing`, `baz`, `bing` logged using a "this-like" variable inside the `bar` function on the prototype of `foo`?

When I say "this-like", I mean, a variable that I could use within `bar()` to access the object that it is a method of both now and later.

Edit:

Further clarification, I'd like to avoid needing to know when I call bar() that it will want to use `this` and that I would therefore need to do something like `bind()`. Assume that when I'm calling `bar()` on baz or bing, that it's a "black box". I want to call bar() as a method of bing or baz without knowing how it works, and I want the internals of bar() to know what object it is a method of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy, if you prefer not to use `bind()`, is to attach your "bound" methods to the object at construction time, referring "indirectly" to `this`.

This:

```
var foo = function(){
  var _this = this;
  this.bar = function() {
    console.log(_this);
  }
}


baz = new foo();
baz.name = 'baz';

bing = new foo();
bing.name = 'bing';

baz.bar();
bing.bar();

setTimeout(baz.bar);
setTimeout(bing.bar);
```

Logs:

```
baz
bing
baz
bing
```

But in general, I like to use `this` when possible so I can `apply()` my methods to other objects if so-desired. And I just encapsulate my "deferred calls" in anonymous functions under the assumption that they use `this`:

```
setTimeout(function() { baz.bar(); });
setTimeout(function() { bing.bar(); });
```

Comment: this looks closer to what I'm after... I'm going to have a quick fiddle with this...

Comment: This is cool but then `var foo = function(){
  var _this = this;
  this.bar = function() {
    console.log(_this);
  }
}

foo.prototype.buzz = function() {
    console.log(_this);
}` breaks for buzz(), which isn't the end of the world but...

Comment: @DavidMeister Yeah. You can't directly see variables used locally in the constructor from prototype methods. A possible workaround is to use a `getBoundThis()` convention. `var _this = this; this.getBoundThis = function() { return _this; }`

Comment: That's fine. I think this is more what I was after than using bind(). Using the constructor to kind of get a "snapshot" of the object the methods are being added to is about as close as I'm going to get.

Comment: Yeah, I think the safest approach is to avoid the prototype for methods that must be strictly bound, but to always *assume* that `this` is used in any object method, and include the paran's in your calls -- which means wrapping your function references / async calls in anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (though you might need to shim it for older browsers):

```
setTimeout(baz.bar.bind(baz));
setTimeout(bing.bar.bind(bing));
// btw,
//         baz.bar.bind(bing)
//         foo.prototype.bar.bind(bing)
// would have the same result
```

Comment: is that not executing immediately, rather than when the timeout fires?

Comment: @DavidMeister Look at some docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind . `bind` returns a new function...it's not invoked anywhere

Comment: No, `bind` returns the bound function that is then scheduled by `setTimeout`

Comment: is there a way to do this though that doesn't require prior knowledge that bar() will try to use `this`?

Comment: Well, you can still use `bind` when the function doesn't access `this` - it will do no harm. Just as you can still call `baz.bar()` while it doesn't access `this`

Comment: @Bergi - are you suggesting that it's a "best practise" to call all methods of all objects with `bind` then, on the off chance they might be relying on `this` being set to the object?

Comment: If you have a generic function that will need to handle arbitrary methods, then yes. But usually you know whether your function needs a context.

Answer (score 0):

These days I do this kind of thing a lot for convenience, no trickery, just scope:

```
function () {

function _this() {
  return window.myObject;
}

window.myObject = {
  myMethod: function myMethod() {
    _this().myOtherMethod();
  },

  myOtherMethod: function myOtherMethod() {

  }
}

}();
```